# MinGW and "declaration does not declare anything"

Tags: g++, compiler-errors, mingw

I'm working on converting a Linux project of mine to compile on Windows using MinGW. It compiles and runs just fine on Linux, but when I attempt to compile it with MinGW it bombs out with the following error message:

```
camera.h:11: error: declaration does not declare anything
camera.h:12: error: declaration does not declare anything
```

I'm kind of baffled why this is happening, because

1. I'm using the same version of g++ (4.4) on both Linux and Windows (via MinGW).
2. The contents of camera.h is absurdly simple.

Here's the code. It's choking on lines 11 and 12 where `float near;` and `float far;` are defined.

```
#include "Vector.h"

#ifndef _CAMERA_H_
#define _CAMERA_H_

class Camera{
public:
  Vector eye;
  Vector lookAt;
  float fov;
  float near;
  float far;
};

#endif
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Thanks both Dirk and mingos, that was exactly the problem!

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong with this. Have you tried removing the `Vector` members and their associated header to exclude them as the problem?

Comment: Include directive should be under the header guard. If a file that includes camera.h also includes Vector.h, you will get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving them different names, like

```
float my_near;
float my_far;
```

I recall Borland using "near" and "far" as keywords (my 1992 Turbo C had these, back in MS-DOS era). Dunno if this is the case with gcc, but you can always try that.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** If you happen to include `windef.h` (either directly or indirectly), you will find

```
#define FAR
#define far
#define NEAR
#define near
```

there. I think, that this is the culprit.

Try

```
#undef near
#undef far
```

before your class definition.

Comment: If downvoters could actually leave a note stating why they downvoted, that would really be helpful.

Comment: I think it's better to use alternate variables names instead of undefining them.

Answer (score 1):

In `<windef.h>`, you'll find on the following lines:

```
#define NEAR
#define near
```

Simple answer: you can't `#undef` them because they're a part of the Windows headers (_WINDEF_H will still be defined even if you `#undef` those definitions, so it won't be re-included if you try to `#include <windef.h>` again, not to mention the fact that if you `#undef _WINDEF_H` before using `#include <windef.h>` after your class definition, you'll end up with duplicate definitions for things like RECT, LONG, PROC and more), so the only other solution is to change your variable names.